# jQuery auto background color transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I tried many ways I found it very simple for me but one thing I can't figure it out. Changing background automatically is working well but it happens very quickly. I wonder is there a solution to make it slow transition now it is very sharp and not user friendly.

```
<script>

$("body").css("transition","all 3s");
var colors = ["#c11733","#c0392b","#66cc99","#27ae60","#745380"];
function changeBgColor(){
   $("body").css({
        backgroundColor : colors[parseInt(Math.random() * 3)]
      });
}
//changeBgColor();
setInterval(changeBgColor, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: it's as mellow as a possible as it is! https://jsfiddle.net/8mLh8gxy/

Comment: wow! but it doesn't work for me. is it up to jquery version or something?

Comment: what browser are you using? you may need prefixes.

Comment: Google Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m and jquery jquery-2.1.4.min

Comment: try adding the `-webkit-` prefix to your transition

Comment: Sorry.. which part of it?

Comment: `$("body").css("-webkit-transition","all 3s");`

Comment: try and see if it has the same problem in other browsers

Comment: I tried IE11 same result.

Comment: If this is not working for you, then you have some other code messing with this one? Because, it works fine for me too. For example, maybe you have 'transition: none !important;' somewhere else attached on the body.

Comment: oh I got it, I think you forgot to put your code in a ready function! try wrapping your code in `$(function(){ //your code here });`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with:

```
<script>
    ( function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
            /* My jQuery Code */
        } );
    } ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```